# C# PHP communication

Tags: c#, php, mysql, windows-phone-8

I'm writing an app that will authenticate user from a MySQL database.
I have written it in Java (android) but am now porting to Windows phone.

the PHP file uses $get and then echoes the response:

```
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];

$query_search = "select * from users where user = '".$username."'";
//$query_search = "select * from users where username = '".$username."' AND password     = '".$password. "'";

$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
if($rows == 0) {
echo "No Such User Found";
} else  {
    echo "User Found";
}
```

How can I pass the username variable to PHP and then receive the result?

Comment: well obviously! I'm going to create encryption and anti injection once I've got the basics.

Comment: @Havondale, that's a recipe for an insecure codebase. Don't wait to make your sql code secure. And no sense learning "the basics" with mysql_* functions--have a look at mysqli_* or the PDO library.

Comment: If it is so obvious then you have ZERO reason to ignore it

Comment: Hypothetically, if I had all the encryption.... What would the answer be?

Comment: do you want to know how to post the username value from windows phone app?

Comment: @Havondale find me on twitter and we will discuss this away from stack overflow. I dont need trolls slamming me while I try and bring you up to speed on how to do this properly and safely

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I fail to see how this is constructive to anyone. Lead by example not by tearing people down. #Flagged

Answer (score 2):

***YOUR CODE IS VULNERABLE TO SQL-INJECTION METHOD USE PDO/MYSQLi to AVOID THIS***

**Create loaded event handler:**

```
using System;
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();

Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}



void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri("Your php page url");
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback),myRequest);
}
```

**creating "POST" data stream:**

```
void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
// End the stream request operation
Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

// Create the post data
string postData = "username=value";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

// Add the post data to the web request
postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
postStream.Close();

// Start the web request
myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
}
```

**receive response:**

```
 void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
    using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new     StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        //For debug: show results
        Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use a in-linky stuff like I have a script in my server and you just write: "example.com/save.php?username=textbox1.text&score=points"